# Why is my microphone circuit not working?

Tags: operational-amplifier, preamp

I'm trying to make a simple microphone/speaker circuit with a `PreAmp` and an `Op-Amp`. Currently, the speaker just outputs a high frequency squeal, and not anything from the microphone.

Looking at the schematic, is there anything you can see that I've done wrong?

[image]

**Datasheets:**

Preamp (INA217) http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina217.pdf

Op-Amp (OPA1652) http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa1652.pdf

-5V (MAX1044) http://pdfserv.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/ICL7660-MAX1044.pdf

---

**Edit 1:**

I've discovered some good news and some bad news. First, the good news! I've eliminated the high pitched tone from the speaker by connecting pin 1 of the MAX1044 to pin 8. The bad news... the circuit still doesn't output any sound from the microphone. So, I've simplified the circuit to try and isolate the problem:

[image]

More good news! Eliminating the OPA1652, I get actual audio from the microphone through the speaker and can adjust the mic gain with the pot and actually gets quite loud on a cheap pair of earbuds.

**Revised question:** Where have I messed up when it comes to the OPA1652 and how should I wire it differently?

For what it's worth, the end goal is to make a small audio mixer. Multiple mic inputs and a single output signal.

Comment: sounds like you are experiencing feedback

Answer (score 1):

If the thing is squealing on its own, then at least one of:

You have feedback path thru the power supply.  This can be remedied by putting a decent amount (several 100 µF) of capacitance between each power supply and ground.

It would also be a good idea to isolate the first stage better from power supply noise.  A chip inductor or two, each followed by 10s of µF to ground might help.  Only the first stage would use this filtered supply.

You have a feedback path thru unintended couping somewhere.  This would be fixed by proper layout.  If you really have a good layout and this is still a problem, then you add guard and/or shield traces.  However, that shouldn't be necessary if the rest is done competently.

You are hearing the noise from the charge pump.  I'm guessing that's a charge pump IC in the lower left corner?  Filtering the supplies to the first stage as described above is necessary to fix this.

Otherwise:

Perhaps the overall gain isn't enough.  You haven't said what the gain of the diff amp is, and the output amp only has a gain of 2.  Usually you need a voltage gain of about 1000 to get microphone signals to line level audio.

You are completely blocking DC to the microphone.  That could be OK, even necessary, if it's a dynamic microphone.  However, if it's a electret, then it needs a DC bias to work.

Comment: it could also be acoustic feedback, the microphone "hearing" the loudspeaker.

Comment: @Jas: Yes, that is also possible, but usually that's very obvious when it happens.  The coupling changes as you move the mic and speaker around, nearby things move around, etc.

Comment: It's definitely not feedback, it did it even without the mic connected. I was able to fix the squeal by connecting pin 1 to pin 8 of the max1044. Please see my updated question.

Answer (score 1):

Try grounding pin 5 of the INA217.

That's how it's shown on the datasheet if you're not using a DC servo.